# PhoneGap local build wp8 create.js not found

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

Issue the command

`phonegap` local build wp8

on Windows for a `PhoneGap 3.4.0` project that already has iOS and Android platforms.

I get the error:

```
ERROR: Could not find 'create.js' in 'bin' folder, aborting...
```

wp8 is added to the platforms folder but the process does not complete.

Would appreciate any insight. Same happens for `PhoneGap 3.1.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend to try the following:

1. Check that there are no spaces in the path where phonegap app is located.
2. Try to remove wp8 template (could be damaged). I'm not sure about Phonegap, for Apache Cordova it is located here (should be similar)

> C:\Users\username\.cordova\lib